# How to get rid of old, deleted user from SharePoint Person or group column suggestions

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, active-directory, windows-server-2019

A user (contoso\John.Smith and display name JSmith) is created in Active Directory in SharePoint 2019 that is on Windows Server 2019.

- This user is added to a person or group column value in couple of list items.
- Further this user is deleted from Active Directory and then created a new user (contoso\JSmith and display name JSmith).
- When I try to resolve JSmith, I now get two users of same name. However, if I try to use invalid user, I get the error message 'This user does not exist or is not unique'.
- If I try to resolve correct/latest user, I am able to save the item.

Steps done so far:

- Removed the user from site collection Users list
- Cleared SharePoint Configuration Cache
- Restarted server, but I am still shown the deleted user again when trying to resolve the user.

[image]

How do I get rid of old deleted user from SharePoint person or group suggestions?